# Php function complete

Tags: php, html

I have a php function what get from my datebase(email,score) score by email,

```
   public function getResults($email){
        $db= $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM score  WHERE email=?');
        $db->execute([$email]);
   }
```

Proablem is I do not know how to finish to result in html score of email.

Comment: You need to do `execute(array(...`. Which API are you using to connect with? Plus, you have a scope issue.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php - http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements depending which API.

Comment: $db->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS); this is api

Comment: Well then, read the PDO manual http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements  - Plus, if the answer given below worked for you, you can accept it in order to mark it as solved. Or, show more code. We can't guess what you have for code in order to make it "work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Fred-ii- says, you have a bit of work ahead of you, but to answer your question you can print the results of the query with:

```
$result=$db->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $result;
```

Comment: Thanks for the mention. However, we don't know which API the OP is using to connect with. If OP is using `mysqli_`, then using `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` won't work. It would be better to show an example for each MySQL API, *just in case*. Both `mysqli_` and PDO use `prepare`.

Comment: use this $db->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);

Comment: I use a class `class myClass{ public function getResults($email) {} }` how I will print $result; in another php page?

Comment: Well, it looks like the question's gone stale. OP's not showing full code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It sucks because OP is probably a good guy trying to get help, but it is very difficult getting started on SO.  It takes a while to get used to how much code is too much/little and what can be assumed and can't.  Hopefully OP is able to solve his problem.

Comment: @user1717828 I know the feeling. Well, *we can't save them all!* Cheers